# Backslash Escape Character in command echo

Tags: bash, quotes

Can anyone explain why **\n** is not working as line break?

```
[user1@localhost ~]$ echo -e a\nb\nc
anbnc
```

Comment: Quoting, quoting, quoting ...

Comment: BTW, [`echo -e` is itself unreliable](https://unix.stackexchange.com/questions/65803/why-is-printf-better-than-echo). Better to use `printf '%b\n' 'a\nb\nc'`; in some configurations (which can be set up at compile-time, at runtime through a command, at runtime through environment variables inherited from a parent process, etc), `echo -e` will write the string `-e` to output! (And that's doubly true in non-bash shells, which may not support `-e` as anything but a string to print at all in the first place).

Answer (score 3):

Use more quotes!

```
$ echo -e 'a\nb\nc'
a
b
c
```

or even better:

```
$ printf 'a\nb\nc'
```

Learn how to quote properly in shell, it's very important:

> "Double quote" every literal that contains spaces/metacharacters and *every* expansion: `"$var"`, `"$(command "$var")"`, `"${array[@]}"`, `"a & b"`. Use `'single quotes'` for code or literal `$'s: 'Costs $5 US'`, `ssh host 'echo "$HOSTNAME"'`. See
> http://mywiki.wooledge.org/Quotes
> http://mywiki.wooledge.org/Arguments
> https://web.archive.org/web/20230224010517/https://wiki.bash-hackers.org/syntax/words
> [when-is-double-quoting-necessary](https://unix.stackexchange.com/questions/68694/when-is-double-quoting-necessary)

Answer (score 0):

A backslash is interpreted by bash to escape the subsequent character. For instance, `foo \*` passes an asterisk to `foo` instead of doing globbing. Similarily, `foo \x` passes a literal `x` to `foo`; escaping is unnecessary, but not forbidden. In your case, the shell turns `a\nb\nc` into `anbnc`.

If you want to pass a literal backslash, you have to use `\\` , for instance

```
echo -e a\\nb\\nc
```

Or you use use single quotes, which escape the whole content in one go:

```
echo -e 'a\nb\nc'
```

Or you don't rely on `echo` doing the newlines, but insert them explicitly:

```
echo  $'a\nb\nc'
```

Or with a HERE document, in which case you have to use `cat` instead of `echo`:

```
cat <<EE
a
b
c
EE
```